# AngularJS Karma testing "Error: Unexpected request: GET" doesn't seem to be executing request

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an AngularJS app that is having some issues in testing.

**Method**

```
PlanService.prototype.getPlanList = function() {
  this.activeRequest = true;
  return this.PlanFactory.planList().then((function(_this) {
    return function(response) {
      _this.plans = response.plans;
      return _this.activeRequest = false;
    };
  })(this));
};

return PlanService;
```

**Unit test:**

```
var planService;
beforeach(function() {
  module("notRealModuleName");
  inject(function(PlanService) {
    planService = PlanService;
  });
});

...(other tests)

it('should get a list of plans', function() {
  var $httpBackend;
  inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  });

  var plans = {"plans": [array of stuff goes here]};
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/plans/special').respond(plans);
  var promise = planService.getPlanList();

  promise.then(function(response) {
     expect(response).toBeDefined();
     expect(planService.plans).toBeDefined();
  });
  $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

When this test executes, the error `Error: Unexpected request: GET http://ip_address/plans/special No more request expected` is returned.  If I comment out the the `httpBackend.flush`, the test passes.  However, if I change the `expect(planService.plans)` to a non-existent method, it doesn't fail.  Clearly, the expectations are not being called.  What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error :

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://ip_address/plans/postpaid No more request expected
```

Means that there is actually no call made to that url, start by double checking the url you'r testing.

In test, for promise to be executed you have to call $rootScope.$digest(); (to avoid asynchronous testing, in the same manner that there is a flush method on $httpBackend), if you add that your test should fail, because the promise will be executed.

Comment: As an addendum to this response: we're using a path factory in this project.  When the path is hard-specified (i.e. '/plans/special') it seems to fail to mock the whenGET.  When the path is specified using the path factory value, it works.  I'm going with that the hard-specified path didn't include the server information.  Therefore, it was hitting the expected mock.  Thanks for the help, @Boris-Charpentier!

Comment: This might also occur when the API GET call needs authentication before being fetched by Karma.